# Rails: Can't assign model object values after migrating to 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migrate

I'm migrating a Rails app from 2.0.2 to 2.3.5.

I have a model class:

```
class EventQuery < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name 'EventQueries'
  def to_s; name; end

end
```

I'm debugging the problem in the console. I try to assign an EventQuery object an attribute:

> ./script/console production 
>   Loading production environment (Rails 2.3.5)

```
>> q=EventQuery.new 
=>  #<EventQuery id: nil, role: nil, name: nil, description: nil, query: nil>
>> q.role="ADM" 
> TypeError: can't convert String into Integer  
from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gem /activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:135:in `[]='
 (...)
```

In Rails 2.0.2 it works fine:

> ./script/console production
>   Loading production environment (Rails 2.0.2)

```
>> q=EventQuery.new
=> #< EventQuery id: nil, role: nil, name: nil, description: nil, query: nil
>> q.role='ADM'
=> "ADM"
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

I'm now thinking this must be related to plugin record_modified which is part of the application.

Comment: It's simply defined as: `role` char(5) NOT NULL. I get the same error when I try to assign any of the other attributes!

Comment: >> EventQuery
    => EventQuery(id: integer, role: string, name: string, description: string, query: text)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to a name conflict with a method in the record_modified plugin. The console works fine if I exclude the plugin from loading.

I have decided to remove the record_modified plugin and refactor the code. Instead of using RecordModified methods I'm using ActiveRecord as follows:

```
RecordModified.modified?  --> ActiveRecord.changed?
RecordModified.changed_columns --> ActiveRecord.changes + minor refactoring
```